# Date format change SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a view with a date column with this format :  `YYYY-MM-DD` and I am using that column in a SSRS report but the final user wants to have something like this:

> December 31, 2018

I am using this expression:

```
=FormatDateTime(Parameters!prmReportDate.Value,DateFormat.LongDate)
```

But I am getting this:

> Monday December 31, 2018

I don't need the day.  Is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
=MonthName(Month(Parameters!prmReportDate.Value),false) 
& " " & 
day(Parameters!prmReportDate.Value)
& "," & 
year(Parameters!prmReportDate.Value)
```

Comment: I mean, that works but why get so complicated and hard code it like that?  Just seems unnecessary considering the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply format the textbox as a date and specify the correct format.  You'll just need to set the expression in the textbox as:

```
=Parameters!prmReportDate.Value
```

And you should be able to set the `Number` format property as:

[image]

And this should give you the output you expect.  If it doesn't work as expected(which actually seems to be the case as I test it), should be able to apply the following expression:

```
=Format(Parameters!prmReportDate.Value, "MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

Just remove one of the `d`s from the expression to remove a leading zero on single digit dates.